# Auto populate price depending on selected product

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter, autocomplete

I have a form with quantity product and price.

```
<form action="" method="POST">
Quantity: <input type="text" name="quantity" id="quantity">
Products: <select name="product" id="product"><option value="1">Product 1</option><option value="2">Product 2</option></select>
Price: <input type="text" name="price" id="price">
<input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

I want to auto populate the price from database for selected product. I tried with alert

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(function() {
        $( "#product" ).autocomplete({
            source: function(request, response) {
                $.ajax({ url: "<?php echo site_url('sales/price'); ?>",
                data: { term: $("#product").val()},
                type: "POST",
                success: function(data){
                    alert(data);
                }
            });
        },
        minLength: 1
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

The sales/price page is returning the price (90.00 or 80.00) for the product id. I trying to pass the product selected value as post and get back the result to set value of price. Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Not sure what your exact question is, but your `select` element has id `product`, whereas your jQuery code selects id `product1`.

Comment: Sorry that was mistakenly typed here

Answer (score 1):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#product").change(function(){
        $.ajax({ 
            url: "<?php echo site_url('sales/price'); ?>",
            data: { product_id: $(this).val() },
            type: "POST",
            success: function(data){
                $('#price').val( data );
            }
        });
    })
});
</script>
```

Try out with this code.

Comment: Thank you. But still same nothing. Please guide me how can i check if ajax is call the page and geting data or not?

Comment: have you used firebug addons? In console tab you can see the ajax call and its answer.